# Sum of Percentage exceeds 100% in winforms pie chart

Tags: c#, winforms, pie-chart

The Sum of Percentage exceeds 100% in Winforms Pie chart with the following datapoints.

```
series.Label = "#PERCENT{P0}"

  series.Points.AddXY("", 3);    // X=0 ,Y =3

  series.Points.AddXY("", 21);   // X=0 ,Y =21
```

[image]

I guess, it could be a rounding issue, Is there any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say rounding issue. 3->12.5% = 13%  and 21->87.5 = 88%. Have you tried putting a decimal point after the integer value. I think it will do integer division and round if not. So replace 3 with 3.0 and 21 with 21.0?

Comment: I tried that as well but issue remains same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series contains { 3, 21 } which add up to 24.  3/24 = 12.5% (in your case 13%) and 21/24 = 87.5% (in your case 88%) due to your #PERCENT{P0} format signifying no decimal places.

The series values are being shown rounded up to the nearest integer.

Change your label format from:

```
series.Label = "#PERCENT{P0}"
```

...to:

```
series.Label = "#PERCENT"
```

Comment: It shows 87.50 % and 12.50 %. But i have to display 88 and 12 like excel chart which always shows the value as 88 % & 12%.

Comment: @C-va Maybe you can run a quick calculation in your app totalling the series as `int`s then `float`s and if there is a discrepancy, round one of the values **down** prior to filling the chart.